# Time complexity to get min elements from max-heap

Tags: algorithm, heap

I was asked in an interview:

> What is the best time complexity in getting the min element(s) from a max-heap?

I replied as O(1) assuming the heap size is known and the heap is implemented as a binary heap using an array. This way as per my assumption, the min value is at `heap_array[heap_size]`.

My question is that if this answer is correct. If not, what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> ***My question is that if this answer is correct.***

No, that's not correct. The only guarantee you have, is that **each node contains the maximum element of the subtree below it**. In other words, **the minimum element can be any leaf** in the tree.

> ***If not what is the correct answer?***

The correct answer is O(n). In each step you need traverse both left and right sub-trees in order to search for the minimum element. In effect, this means that you need to traverse all elements to find the minimum.

Comment: Couldn't we also just look at the last ceil(n/2) elements of the array. It is still O(n).

Comment: @GuruDevanla It sounds like the question does not specify an implementation. Making assumptions about the implementation would/should not be valid, I would think.

Comment: ** Even if we could also just look at the last cells (n/2) elements of the array. It is still O(n)

Answer (score 11):

Best complexity is `O(n)`. Sketch proof:

- The minimum element could be absolutely any of the lowest-level nodes (in fact it could even not be at the lowest level, but let's start with these).
- There could be up to `n/2` lowest-level nodes.
- All of them need to be examined, because the one you're looking for might be in the last place you look. Examining all-but-1 of them doesn't tell you whether the last one is the minimum or not.
- Hence `Omega(n)` examinations required.

The bound is tight, since clearly we can do it in `O(n)` by ignoring the fact that our array happens to be a heap.

Moral: it's probably called a heap because (as with the heap of clothes on your bedroom floor) it's easy to get at the top and difficult to get at the rest.

Comment: +1. But I would simply say, "could be any of the leaf nodes".

Comment: @aioobe: that would probably be better, since I'm pretty sure there are guaranteed to be at least `n/2` leaf nodes, which makes the `Omega`-bound more obvious.

Comment: "in fact it could even not be at the lowest level" -- What would be an example where the min element is not at the lowest level?

Comment: @Mansoor: The max-heap property is that every child is smaller than its parent. Nothing about siblings. So consider a heap with "10" at the root. It has two children "1" and "9". The "9" has two children "8" and "7". Then the smallest value is not at the lowest level (although necessarily it is a leaf node).

Answer (score 1):

Min element from Max heap :

1. search at last level = O(n/2)= O(n)
2. replace searched element with last element and decrease heap size by 1 = O(1)
3. Apply Maxheapify on replaced element = O(log n)

**Total Time = O(n)+O(1)+O(log n) = O(n)**

Answer (score 1):

MINIMUM_ELEMENT -> it will take O(n) time in case of Max heap and O(1) in case of Min heap.
MAXIMUM_ELEMENT -> it will take O(1) time in case of Max heap and O(n) in case of Min heap.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is O(n)
1) to find minimum element from max heap 
        Find nth max(which is nothing but minimum element)
        Which will take n(n-1)/2 comparisons == O(n^2)
2) first at all it is array
        To find minimum element apply selection sort 1st pass
         Which will take O(n) time.
3) delete one by one (upto) n elements in max heap(it is nothing but finding only)
         Which will take O(nlogn) time.
Among 3 ways the best one is O(n).
So correct answer will be O(n) time

Answer (score 0):

Best complexity is O(n).

Rather than, not wrote here a lot about that,
The **min** element in **MAX-heap**, and the **MAX** element in **min-heap**
Can be also at the (lowest level - 1) and not always in lowest level.

explain:
because in heap there is an option of missing nodes from the right side of the lowest level, it could be not a balancing (fully) tree, what makes it to have leafs also in (lower level -1).

what means that there are n/2 to check.
so in big O term it's equal to **O(n)**.

**Examples** for situation like that:

- MAX-heap[10,9,1,8,7] (1 is the smaller value, but didnt apear in lowest level)
- min-heap [8,10,20,17,15] (20 is the max value, but didnt apear in lowest level)